# Trying to get exist cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to get exist cookie with the following code:

```
  function readCookie(name) {

    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');

    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        console.log(c);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have the cookie name but i'm always getting NULL.

I see the cookie at the developer tool (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/manage-data/cookies)

but `document.cookie` is `""`

Comment: *"I need to change some configuration at the server side?"* I thought I understood your question, but now I don't. You want to use client-side javascript to change something on the server?

Comment: No, I'm just want to get the cookie

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set cookie and get cookie with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript)

Comment: Are you sure that the cookie exists and includes `name`? [Check with your browser debugger.](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/manage-data/cookies)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create and read a value from cookie?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)

Comment: Your function works on my cookies.

Comment: @Blazemonger, Yeah i'm sure the cookie is exists but i cant get the cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```js
function readCookie(name){
    var nameEQ = name+"=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) !=-1) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
document.cookie="name=sagar;expire=";
console.log(readCookie(`name`));
```

Comment: I want to get the exist cookie that I see at this list: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/manage-data/cookies

Comment: The last 2 lines are sample data. You can pass any coockie name to the function.

Comment: Yeah, but i have exist cookie, why i need to create a new one?

Comment: You don't have to create it. You can ignore the last 2 lines. It is only to show example usage

Comment: Your code is exactly what i'm already tried.. i'm always get null from this function

Comment: From your updated question, if document.cookie is null, it means there is no cookie at all.

Comment: But I see the cookie at Chrome dev tool

Comment: can you take a screenshot of both chrome dev tool and `document.cookie;` in console with visible url